How to present private YouTube videos in an Angular application
I'm writing this question because I didn't find anything that would clarify this question.
I'm trying to use the YouTube API to display private videos from a YouTube channel in my Angular application in version 13.2.0.
I've already tried using angular-oauth2-oidc but no version seems to be compatible with the Angular version, always showing errors when trying to install and use it.
I would like someone to explain to me how this can be done, I really need guidance.
I appreciate any contribution.
I tried installing the package this way:
npm install angular-oauth2-oidc --legacy-peer-deps
however, it has errors.
This is my current package.json:
{
  "name": "acg-ui",
  "version": "1.0.7",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serves",
    "build": "ng build",
    "watch": "ng build --watch --configuration development",
    "test": "ng test"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^13.2.2",
    "@angular/cdk": "^13.2.2",
    "@angular/common": "~13.2.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "~13.2.0",
    "@angular/core": "~13.4.0",
    "@angular/forms": "~13.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~13.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~13.2.0",
    "@angular/router": "~13.2.0",
    "chart.js": "^4.4.0",
    "keycloak-angular": "^9.1.0",
    "keycloak-js": "^16.1.1",
    "ngx-linkifyjs": "^1.3.0",
    "primeflex": "^3.1.2",
    "primeicons": "^5.0.0",
    "primeng": "^13.1.1",
    "quill": "^1.3.7",
    "rxjs": "~7.5.0",
    "tslib": "^2.6.2",
    "zone.js": "~0.11.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~13.2.2",
    "@angular/cli": "~13.2.2",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~13.2.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.10.0",
    "@types/node": "^12.11.1",
    "jasmine-core": "~4.0.0",
    "karma": "~6.3.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage": "~2.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "~4.0.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "~1.7.0",
    "typescript": "~4.5.2"
  }
}


Hi there! Please read how to ask for more information about asking good questions on StackOverflow. For instance, what's the error?
